# load content of one HTML template on div of another HTML template using DJANGO

Tags: python, django, iframe

am new to django concept , so i want to include one html template inside div of another html template . i tried using iframe but when i load the page it says localhost refused to connect , then i referred some of the stack answers and i did it with include but when i give include the page is not loading .

**IndexPage.html**

```
 <section id="testimonial" class="testimonial section-padding">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div id="testimonials" class="owl-carousel wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.2s">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="testimonial-item">
                  <div class="info">
                    <!-- <iframe id="encoder_iframe" height=75% width="50%" src='/templates/index.html'></iframe> -->
                    {% include "index.html" %}
                    
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h1 class="page-header"></h1>

  <p class="lead"></p>
  <p class="lead"><a href="/products">Customer ListList</a>.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def IndexPage(request):
    return render(request,'IndexPage.html',{})

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def product_list(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'product_list.html', {'products': products})


def save_product_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            products = Product.objects.all()
            data['html_product_list'] = render_to_string('includes/partial_product_list.html', {
                'products': products
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def product_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    return save_product_form(request, form, 'includes/partial_product_create.html')


def product_update(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=product)
    else:
        form = ProductForm(instance=product)
    return save_product_form(request, form, 'includes/partial_product_update.html')


def product_delete(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product.delete()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        products = Product.objects.all()
        data['html_product_list'] = render_to_string('includes/partial_product_list.html', {
            'products': products
        })
    else:
        context = {'product': product}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('includes/partial_product_delete.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

so have to include index.html inside div of indexpage.html

[structure of folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20r46.png)

Comment: What are you trying to load in the <a href="/products"> ?

Comment: that is where my product list will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

probably, Django doesn't know where to take index.html from. Have you placed {% load static %} at the top of IndexPage.html?

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the product_list  to  "/products"  ?

Changing "/products" to "{% url 'product_list' %}  may help.

Comment: when i give something like that it just gives loading widget and will not load anycontent